# GWT: Is it possible to refer non-GWT modules that contain GWT-independent presenters?

Tags: gwt, mvp, gwt2, platform-agnostic

For curiosity's sake, I'm developing a small experimental platform/environment-agnostic MVP framework-like thing that's supposed to be as much platform independent as possible. Currently it consists of dumb models, platform-independent presenters (defined in a single abstract main application module), and platform-dependent views (currently there are experiments with Swing, Android and terminal-friendly environment). However, I'm in trouble trying to make GWT another available platform because it requires modules inheritance via `.gwt.xml` files. Is there a good way of inheriting non-GWT modules somehow, and keep that abstract platform-independent module `.gwt.xml`-free, but still available for the GWT? If it's worthy: all modules are built with Maven, and the project structure is as follows:

```
[root]
    [app]                --- platform-independent application
        pom.xml              -- references fx
    [app-gwt]            --- GWT-views, entry point, etc
        pom.xml              --- references app, fx, fx-gwt
        .... App.gwt.xml     --- references Fx.gwt.xml
    [fx]                 --- the core itself
        pom.xml              --- references nothing
    [fx-gwt]             --- GWT-specific adapters for the fx module
        pom.xml              --- references fx
        .... Fx.gwt.xml      --- references GWT core
    pom.xml
```

Simply speaking, I don't want either `app` or `fx` to be GWT-related in any case. Also, I thought that modifying `<source path="...">` (referencing to another module source code) can help, but I can't make it work (if it's possible). Here are some similar questions, not sure they can help:

- [inherit a non gwt module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236165/inherit-a-non-gwt-module)
- [Inherit external java source in GWT project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688325/inherit-external-java-source-in-gwt-project) (similar concept)

Thanks.

(For simplicity, let's assume that `app` and `fx` have no external dependencies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've investigated the problem deeper, and the general solution is:

- Supply the dependencies source code to the dependency repository using the `maven-source-plugin` plugin. This step is a must because GWT compiles the dependency source code rather than using JAR.
- Define a regular GWT module with `inherit` elements to make dependencies.
- Compile the target application using `gwt-maven-plugin` with the `compileSourcesArtifacts` configuration option set to match the dependencies.

See more at http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/library.html